# How do I open a read-only SQLite database located in a WAR file?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I'm deploying a servlet WAR, using a read-only SQLite database. How should I open it?

Right now I'm using `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:ABSOLUTEDIR/myDb.db");` on my test-server but I want to include it in my WAR to ease deployment.

Can I open it as `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:myDb.db");` and where should I put the myDb.db?

Comment: have you actually tried?

Comment: @SalvadorJuanMartinez yes. I put it into the "servlet" container root (such as http://localhost:8080/myRoot/myDb.db if http://localhost:8080/myRoot/WEB_INF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Servlet-Containers support the calling of [getRealPath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)) on ServletContext. At least if you run your war as an exploded webapp.

Once you get a hold on your ServletContext, you can then do:

```
 ServletContext ctx = //you need to do this
 String dbPath = ctx.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/sql.db");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+dbPath);
```

Good luck and merry Xmas